# Search for specific row in CSV-file with PHP and echo specific field of this row

Tags: php, csv

I am a newbie and have a small PHP question! I have a CSV file that changes often its content. Let's say:

```
PRODUCT; DESC; PRICE
32; X; 900
37; X; 1200
4; X; 82
```

Please note: Ordner of items can change!

I want now to echo for example the description of the product "37".

I was trying fgetcsv but was just able the echo whole file:

```
$row = 1;
if (($handle = fopen("test.csv"; "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $num = count($data);
        echo "<p> $num fields in line $row: <br /></p>\n";
        $row++;
        for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
            echo $data[$c] . "<br />\n";
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

How can I access a specific field of a specific row (which I want to find with a keyword = Product)?

Thanks for any help for a beginner!

Comment: You mean something like to find product 4, would be something like `$data[0] == "4"`?

Comment: Yes, I just want to echo for example the description of product 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To only get one product, 37 for example, you can use an if condition :

```php
$row = 1;
if (($handle = fopen("test.csv"; "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $num = count($data);
        echo "<p> $num fields in line $row: <br /></p>\n";
        $row++;
        if ($data[0] == '37') {
            // do something with your row
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

`$data[0]` is your product id, `$data[1]` is your desc and `$data[2]` the price.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get csv row by header key reference

```
function get_csv_row($path=null,$key=null,$search=null){
        if(empty($path) || empty($key)){
            return array();
        }

        $row_num =1;$search_row=array();
        if (($handle = fopen($path, "r")) !== FALSE) {
            while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
                
                if($row_num==1){
                    $header_csv = $data;
                    $row_num=2;
                    continue;
                }

                $row_data=array_combine($header_csv, $data);

                if(isset($row_data[$key]) && trim($row_data[$key]) == $search){
                    $search_row = $data;
                    break;
                }

                $row_num++;
            }
        }
        fclose($handle);
        return $search_row;
    }
```